# using methods and constructors to construct a basic calculator in java

Tags: java

I want to come up with a simple basic calculator but am supposed to work with the following constructors and methods

```
simpleCalc();
simpleCalc(double op1, double op2);
double add();
double add(double op1, double op2);
double mult();
double mult(double op1, double op2);
double exp();
double exp(double op1, double op2);
void show();
void show(int dp);
```

The methods should do the following: The constructors, simpleCalc, should initialize
the calculator with the operands (if provided – otherwise, it initializes to 0 and 1
respectively); add should perform the addition operation on the operands (provided), store
and return the result; mult should perform the multiplication operation on the operands
(provided), store and return the result; exp should perform the operation of exponentiation
on the operands (op1^op2), store and also return the result; show should print out the current
result in the calculator correct to the given number of decimal places (default: 2dp).

Any idea on how to implement it

Comment: write unit tests to check if your code works or not !

Comment: There are few things, declaring empty non-arg constructor is not necessery, you could use default constructor which do same thing, not sure why you defined non-arg operation methods, and last thing, your exp function will not work if op2 will be fraction or negative value, and really last thing, this question will fits better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user902383 declaring a non-arg constructor is necessary if you declare an arg constructor because you then lose the default no arg constructor. the fact that it's empty now doesn't matter. could get filled in the future.

Comment: Think of what you learned about classes. What kind of member can you use that will be available to all of your methods (private, public, or otherwise)? When can you set these members?

Comment: @blueygh2 maybe is something wrong with my eyes, but i havent seen there any other constructor. and if there is not any, then as i said there are no need to define one.

Comment: @user902383 not in the functional code bits, but OP listed arg constructor as requirement

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework.

You're going in the right direction, however, you are not storing anything, as you say you are supposed to in the introduction. Your operations without arguments don't actually work.

As I understand it, you can create a new calculator with default values 0 and 1 or with custom values. However, once you say calc.add(1,3); the calculator should save the values 1 and 3, so that when you call calc.mult(), it will multiply these values.

You would need to store the values somehow. That's all I'm gonna say for now.

Answer (score 0):

This question should really be on [CodeReview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Your code looks fine (except for what blueygh2 said in their answer), although the multiplication operator should be `*`, `simpleCalc` should be named `SimpleCalc` to meet Java standards and `exp` can be replaced with a faster version using `Math.pow()`:

```
double exp(double op1, double op2)
{
    return op1 * Math.pow(10, op2);
}
```

The `pow()` method raises the first argument to the power of the second argument.

Comment: in *her* answer? I also thought about Math.pow(), but maybe they are not allowed to use that.

Comment: @blueygh2 Sorry, I was autocorrected from `ther` while trying to type `their` :P Also, I was trying to teach the OP a bit of Java - indeed, they may not be allowed to use `Math` but it will help them in future to know that it is available and preferred.

Comment: math.pow() is not allowed but i will take note of that thanks

Comment: Your example is wrong. It should be `return Math.pow(op1, op2);`.